# Twitter API with react JS

Tags: javascript, twitter, reactjs

I managed to get the following twitter account button working with react with this code:

```
class TwitterShareButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <a href="https://twitter.com/share" className="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var scriptNode = document.getElementById('twitter-wjs')
    if (scriptNode) {
      scriptNode.parentNode.removeChild(scriptNode)
    }

    !function(d,s,id){
      var js,
          fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
      if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
  }
}
```

from http://qiita.com/h_demon/items/95e638666f6bd479b47b

How can I bind the events? https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events

I added

```
var twttr = document.getElementById('twitter-wjs')

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  // Now bind our custom intent events
  twttr.events.bind('click', clickEventToAnalytics);
  twttr.events.bind('tweet', tweetIntentToAnalytics);
  twttr.events.bind('retweet', retweetIntentToAnalytics);
  twttr.events.bind('like', likeIntentToAnalytics);
  twttr.events.bind('follow', followIntentToAnalytics);
});
```

to `componentDidMount`. It didn't work.

Comment: Where are the callback functions in your code? Also, what didn't work? Is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: the click events aren't working -- I want to track when the button is click or when the account is followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `window.twttr` directly rather than `document.getElementById` - and do this inside `componentDidMount`.

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a href='https://twitter.com/share' className='twitter-share-button' ref='share' data-url='https://twitter.com/'>Tweet</a>
    );
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log("Clicked");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.twttr.events.bind('click', this.onClick);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Twitter Share</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
  </script>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Edit to take feedback into consideration*: As per the documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading) and what the script you are including inside your `index.html` does, `window.twttr` is assigned and ready for you to use. You don't need to access any other elements - go straight to using `window.twttr` in order to bind events. There is a bind for clicks, you can add more as you like and assign them to appropriate callbacks that you create.

Comment: Don't use shortened URLs, they are likely to vanish without warning. It's also better to have the entire code here rather than in an external link as that may change or vanish too.

Comment: Add explanation for the code also, so the OP understands where is the problem.

Comment: Much better, well done! Oh, and there's no need to have the code as a snippet as it's not runnable, simple code blocks will suffice.

Comment: thanks! you forgot `twttr.widgets.load()` in `componentDidMount`. Works after adding that